# Can I override the properties and functions of a generically typed interface extending a non generic interface to consider generic type(s) in C#

Tags: c#, generics

What I have is a non generic interface for the purpose of having a common contact that I can call functions. The interface returns objects which implement other interfaces. For example:

```
public interface ISearchAdvancedInputController
{
    ISearchAdvancedInput GetAdvancedInput();
    void LoadFromModel(ISearchAdvancedInput advancedInput);
}
```

I then currently have an abstract generic class which implements the interface but imposes requirements of the type. The types of the abstract class must implement the same interfaces as the interface's properties and functions demand. I cast the generic type to the implemented type when necessary so that I can satisfy the requirements of the implemented non abstract interface. This way, I can extend this abstract class and it will enforce type requirements across a larger class w/ many different types used across it. For example:

```
public abstract class ISearchAdvancedInputControllerBase<standardInput, advancedInputType> : ISearchAdvancedInputController
    where advancedInputType : ISearchAdvancedInput
{
    protected abstract advancedInputType GetAdvancedInput();

    ISearchAdvancedInput ISearchAdvancedInputController.GetAdvancedInput()
    {
        return GetAdvancedInput();
    }

    void ISearchAdvancedInputController.LoadFromModel(ISearchAdvancedInput advancedInput)
    {
        LoadFromModel((advancedInputType)advancedInput);
    }

    public abstract void LoadFromModel(advancedInputType advancedInput);
}
```

This works really well in general however it falls short because I'm having to use an abstract CLASS in order to perform this overriding. As such when I want to actually make use of it for more concrete examples, I encounter the error that I can only extend a single class.

So to get around this I extend the "other" class in the previous base abstract class. However this is not ideal because if I wind up creating another concrete implementation I need to redefine all of the type translations that I'm doing which is NOT related to the concrete classes implementation.

What I'd like is to not have an abstract class but instead some sort of abstract interface. If I had this I'd be able to implement concrete classes more succinctly. I've looked at other instances of this question and have tried what seems to be the main suggestion which is to make the initial interface generic and have the type extend the resulting interface type and then extend that interface with the more abstract interface as such:

```
interface TestGenericInterface<a> where a:TestClassInterfaceA
{
    TestClassInterfaceA testGeneric { get; }
}

interface TestGenericComplexInterface<a> : TestGenericInterface<a>
    where a:TestClassInterfaceA
{
    new a testGeneric { get; }
}
```

However the concrete class seems to suffer from the same issue that's shown when you start from a non generic interface where each function / property of the base interface needs overwritten.

```
public class TestClass : TestGenericComplexInterface<TestGC>
{
    public TestGC testGeneric => I want to complete this because its return is the type that I'm wanting to use for this concrete implementation

    TestClassInterfaceA TestGenericInterface<TestGC>.testGeneric => I don't want to have to complete this because this function is already handled by the previous function in a round about sense.
}

public class TestGC : TestClassInterfaceA { }
```

I do see a note that I could provide default implementation of functions if I use c# v8.0 or greater, so I must be on a version prior to that but I figure this should be possible w/o that, but maybe in a different way. Hope ya'll can assist.

Comment: I share this blog post a lot. It's not derogatory, just based on experience. I'm not saying that it describes this scenario, but maybe you'll find it helpful. https://scotthannen.org/blog/2018/04/05/the-generic-rabbit-hole-of-madness.html

Comment: Its definitely an interesting read. The issue this fails to address is the fact that many large components are often the exact same thing just represented a lot of different ways. A search control, like is my case, really only needs a single implementation. It should be generic and many groups of developers often rebuild the exact same thing thinking there'll be different, when in fact its not and hardly ever is. What this blog advises is that we all just build our own search controls and tie all the pieces together ourselves and it's that mentality, imo, that sets teams of developers back.

Comment: Inheritance tends to make it harder. And I think adding lots of generics implies that we're going to meet new requirements using many of the same classes and interfaces. That couples things together. That's why I always recommend writing a simpler implementation for one thing and for the next thing, and then we learn something about how they converge. Then the commonality and the use of generics becomes clearer.

Comment: Yes interfaces makes it harder to freestyle. Unstructured code is definitely easier to write on a one off basis. But it's also easier to break and not nearly as readable because it's often hastily thrown together. When you have systems where many different developers jump between projects, having the application or page define it's requirements means that documentation can actually be fully encompassing, but also that as long as the developers follow the blueprint defined by the intended interface they are sure to get a working product on every implementation.